# jQuery check if it is clicked or not

Tags: jquery

```
$( element ).click( function() {

});
```

How can I check if the element is clicked or not? I'm doing like that

```
function element() {
    $( "#element" ).click( function() {
        return 0;
    } );
}
if( element() == 0 ) {
    alert( "yes" );
} else {
    alert( "no" );
}
```

But it's not returning anything.

Comment: You cannot `return` from an event handler. Please describe the actual problem you are trying to solve. When exactly do you want to check whether the element was clicked or not?

Comment: I have two functions and i want to start the second function based on the click event, if the first function returns 0 that means click to start the second function, and if not to start it but with different parameters

Comment: So you basically want to call a function on the first click and the same function with different parameters on the second (and further) click(s)?

Comment: No actualy i want to see if it is clicked so i can make furder logics .. so if it is clicked to start th efunction with one parameters,and if not with other. Felix your code is working, but it is working only when the logic is is the click and i don't need like that

Comment: @gamb: Well, you don't have to do the testing inside the click handler. You can do it outside when-/wherever you want.

Comment: Felix the events are started automatic when the page loads,

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could use [**`.data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$("#element").click(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

and then check it with:

```
if($('#element').data('clicked')) {
    alert('yes');
}
```

To get a better answer you need to provide more information.

**Update:**

Based on your comment, I understand you want something like:

```
$("#element").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('clicked')) {
        func(some, other, parameters);
    }
    else {
        $this.data('clicked', true);
        func(some, parameter);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yea affter a lot of changes of my code i did it, it was similar way so tnx to all , and check is for u.

Comment: What if element has two buttons? So same ids but different classes?

Comment: @JohnSmith: not sure what you mean. It doesn't matter to how many elements the handler is attached to. It always operates on the clicked element.

Answer (score 9):

Using jQuery, I would suggest a shorter solution.

```
var elementClicked;
$("element").click(function(){
   elementClicked = true;
});
if( elementClicked != true ) {
    alert("element not clicked");
}else{
    alert("element clicked");
}
```

("element" here is to be replaced with the actual name tag)

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
    var listh = document.getElementById( 'list-home-list' );
    var hb = document.getElementsByTagName('hb');
    $("#list-home-list").click(function(){
    $(this).style.color = '#2C2E33';
    hb.style.color = 'white';
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should explain what your code snippet does. And further it is better if you nudge the user towards the correct solution if the solution is a simple one instead of posting the the solution as it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var val;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#click").click(function () {
                val = 1;
                get();
                });
                });
          function get(){
            if (val == 1){
                alert(val);
                }

          }
</script>
    <table>
    <tr><td id='click'>ravi</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Do what ever logic you want in the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, before I go into the solution, lets be on the same line about this one fact: Javascript is Event Based. So you'll usually have to setup callbacks to be able to do procedures.

Based on your comment I assumed you have a trigger that will do the logic that launched the function depending if the element is clicked; for sake of demonstration I made it a "submit button"; but this can be a timer or something else.

```
var the_action = function(type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'a':
            console.log('Case A');
            break;
         case 'b':
            console.log('Case B');
            break;
    }
};

$('.clickme').click(function() { 
    console.log('Clicked');
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});

$('.submit').click(function() {
    // All your logic can go here if you want.
    if($('.clickme').data('clicked') == true) {
        the_action('a');
    } else {
        the_action('b');
    }
});
```

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/6MCVJ/

Answer (score 1):

This is the one that i've tried & it works pretty well for me

```
$('.mybutton').on('click', function() {
       if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
           //do your stuff here if the button is not clicked
           $(this).data('clicked', true);
       } else {
           //do your stuff here if the button is clicked
           $(this).data('clicked', false);
       }

   });
```

for more reference check this link
[JQuery toggle click](https://codepen.io/trickymind/pen/bGGyaxJ)