# Ensure user clicked on dynamically generated external links before submitting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make sure that a user must have clicked on external links (which pop up a new page) before submitting.

Is there a simple way to do this that will work on all major browsers?

UPDATE:there may be several of these links which are dynamically generated. need to make sure each one has been clicked

Comment: please have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6081658/1940720

Comment: @MuhammedAslamC thanks but element is generated dynamically. i added this point to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this helps you? Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/g37N7/)**</kbd>.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
```

---

```
$(function() {
  // For demo purposes
  $('body').prepend('<a href="http://google.com" class="ext">Google</a>' +
                    '<a href="http://google.com" class="ext">Google</a>' +
                    '<a href="http://google.com" class="ext">Google</a>' +
                    '<a href="http://google.com" class="ext">Google</a>' +
                    '<a href="http://google.com" class="ext">Google</a>');

  $(document).on('click','.ext', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('ext','clicked');
    if($('.ext').length === 0) {
       $('input[name="submit"]').prop('disabled',false);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: there may be several links. need to make sure each one was clicked. not just one of them

Comment: Oh...I'll try to find solution ;)

Comment: thank you but needs to be foolproof. the links pop up an edit page and the user may well click one several times.

Comment: Ok now it's foolproof I think ;)

Comment: does this work if the links are added after $(document).on statement?

Comment: It should I think, try ;)

Comment: ok will try it out... thnx :-) only problem is that the number of links is unknown.

Comment: You're welcome ;) Now it works with unknown number of links. Fiddle updated.

Comment: isn't the second argument to toggleclass supposed to be a boolean?

Comment: No `clicked` in this case is the new class name not event, you could write anything you want. `toggleClass()` removes first class adds another.

Comment: are you sure? the documentation says no like that https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: `.toggleClass('ext','clicked');` is equivalent to `.removeClass('ext').addClass('clicked');`.

Comment: hmm. i see this in the doc .toggleClass( className, switch )

Comment: Yeah but I'm not using the switch just another class ;) and about the [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

Answer (score 2):

declare a global variable:

```
window.clicked = false;
```

Then on the link's onclick, do this:

```
<a href="some external link" onclick="clicked=true;">Hi</a>
```

Now if the user had clicked the external link, `clicked` will have `true` else `false`.

Based on that, do your logic