# jQuery If Else Statement Not Working Here

Tags: jquery, if-statement

want asking a question about If Else Statement on jQuery.

**this my code looks like :**

```
$(document).ready(function (){

  var click = $('header').click;

  if(click){
    $('header ul li').slideDown();
  }
});
```

**i've tried this too:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){

  var click = $('header');

  if(header).click(function ()){
    $('header ul li').slideDown();
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? `click()` doesn't return anything that's useful to test with `if`.

Comment: `.click()` just binds an event handler. It returns the jQuery object it was applied to, so that calls can be chained. jQuery objects are always true.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081608/jquery-check-if-it-is-clicked-or-not?

Comment: You've also got a couple of typos where you haven't closed quotes.

Comment: in my case, i want to remove the fontawesome icon on the list, its look like this http://jsfiddle.net/uct5exkz/ @Barmar

Comment: I don't see any relationship between this question and that fiddle. And there's no fontawesome icon anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('header').click(function (){
   $('header ul li').slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your if statement is always returning true is that the `$('header').click` attribute is a function. Functions are truthy and pass truth tests. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here. If you're wanting to know if there are click handlers registered, you can do:

```
var events = $._data($("headel ul li")[0], "events");

if(events && events.click && events.click.length) {
    alert("True!");
}
```