# jquery .data() is not attaching data to element

Tags: jquery, html, events

I would like it so when the user clicks on the "2" button (code below) a data attribute of `clicked = true` should appear on the button. eventually I would like it so that when user clicks on the "3" button the "2" button `clicked` data should be removed and the 3 button data attribute should be `clicked = true`. right now it looks like i cant do a simple thing like placing the data on the element and interact with it

HTML:

```
<body>
    <button class = "two">2</button>
    <button class="three">3</button>
</body>
```

Script:

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
          //when user clicks on button the button should show signs of data attr
            $('.two').on('click',function(e){
                $(this).data('clicked', true);
                //alert('sup')
            })
            if($('.two').data('clicked')){
                alert('received from data')
            }
  });
```

I tried following [this chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081608/jquery-check-if-it-is-clicked-or-not) to toggle that data attr so i could figure out which element is clicked to perform operations later in my code

Comment: the `if` is running before the `click` handler (*and never again since it is in the `.ready` method*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to store the clicked button to retrieve later.

In such case it will be better to use a class based solution like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //when user clicks on button the button should show signs of data attr
  var $clicks = $('.clicks').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $clicks.not(this).removeClass('clicked');
  });

  $('#test').click(function() {
    alert($('.clicks.clicked').text())
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="two clicks">2</button>
<button class="three clicks">3</button>
<br />
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

---

If you want to continue sing `data-clicked` attribute, you need to use `.attr()` not `.data()` as `.data()` does not update the attribute value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //when user clicks on button the button should show signs of data attr
  var $clicks = $('.clicks').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('data-clicked', 'true');
    $clicks.not(this).removeAttr('data-clicked');
  });

  $('#test').click(function() {
    alert($('.clicks[data-clicked]').text())
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="two clicks">2</button>
<button class="three clicks">3</button>
<br />
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Comment: hi this was helpful but i was wondering if you could help me with my next prob. I will accept your answer. in the http://jsfiddle.net/fvu3n5h5/ i am trying to get the amount variable to be updated on the click of the button. my logic is that if '2 button' is clicked `amount` will be 2 and if 3button is clicked `amount will be three` how do i get amount to update. thanks ..so when i click on test it should show the value for amount

Comment: this looks great. thanks. I like the first  jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gtqacbr9/1 since it is similar to what i had. I think my main prob in the fiddle was that i used "==" instead of assigning "=".  didn't work because "==" is not used for assigning variables? it's mostly used for testing? thanks for your help

Comment: `==` is used for comparision `=` for assignment