# Why 'attr' only works in first element

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function: depends if a button is clicked or not, I storage if this happens with `attr`.

The behavior is: first you click any item list, and then "Item1" or "Item2".
If any of the item list is already clicked, the background must change to red. Else must change to pink.

It seems to work, but when I try to test it, only works if the clicked item list is the first.

Also tried with `data()` as seen on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081608/jquery-check-if-it-is-clicked-or-not), but with [same result](https://jsfiddle.net/u4e3cnbz/).

I have achieved what I want with 'hasClass', but I don't know what's wrong with my function. Why this only works in first element with `data` or `attr`?

```js
 $("footer ul li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).attr('data-clicked', 'true');
   });




 $("dl dt").click( function () {
  if ($("footer ul li").attr("data-clicked")) {
   $("body").css("background", "red");
  } else {
   $("body").css("background", "pink");
  };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
<ul>
    <li id="#foo">Item list 1</li>
    <li id="#bar">Item list 2</li>
</ul>

<dl>
<dt>Item 1</dt>

    <dd>Description 1</dd>
<dt>Item 2</dt>

    <dd>Description 2</dd>
</dl>
    </footer>
```

Comment: you can't use an if statement with .attr() - at least not how you are trying to. actually you're not using it correctly at all.

Comment: Um, attr will set it to all the elements, are you misreading something? (edit - And I see by your comment you only read the GET portion.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such situations please refer to the manual/docs. As stated in [jQuery API documentation on .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> Get the value of an attribute for the **first** element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is no different:

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the **first** element in the set of matched elements.