# Javascript textarea select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any event for the `textarea` that will fire as your dragging your mouse making a selection across the text? For example, the event would fire when you first click inside of the `textarea` and would continue to fire as you drag your mouse making a selection. The event would stop firing after you have let go of the mouse click button, leaving some of the text selected.

Comment: "event would fire when you first click inside of the textarea and would **continue** to fire as you drag your mouse making a selection"

Comment: you can use mousedown and mouseup

Comment: Not that I know of, but you could use a global variable as a catch, with the events `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` and use `onmousemove` to fire the event.

Comment: yes that will work. I don't know how I forgot about that :P

Comment: see this too , can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081608/jquery-check-if-it-is-clicked-or-not

Comment: It would probably be better to just use the [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/select) event which will fire once selection is done. Is there an actual need for an event that would fire multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

you can catch mousemove and check for buttons properties, if buttons equals 1 then left mouse is clicked.

```
function fire(selectedtext){
   console.log(selectedtext);
}

$( ".textarea" ).mousemove(function( event ) {

  if(event.buttons==1)
  {
    var seltext = $(".textarea").val().substring(this.selectionStart,this.selectionEnd);
    if(seltext.length > 0) fire(seltext );

  }
});
```