# get a boolean value for a specific button being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm working on a music player using Javascript/JQuery but I don't quite get how to write out the conditions. The way I want to set it up is

```
    if(currentSong is paused AND the play button is clicked){
         //do something
    }else if(currentSong is playing AND pause button is clicked){
         //do something else
    }
```

So far I have,

```
    var togglePlayButton = function(){
            var $playPauseButton = $('.main .play-pause');
            if(currentSong.isPaused() && $playPauseButton.html(playButton).clicked == true){
                  //do something
            }else if(currentSong && $playPauseButton.html(pauseButton).clicked == true){
                 //do something else
            }
    }
     $(document).ready(function() {

         $playPauseButton.click(togglePlayButton);

     });
```

What can I do to get a boolean value for the case of the play/pause being clicked? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an event listener on the buttons? Is the above condition in the function called when the event triggers? We may need to see more code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery check if it is clicked or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081608/jquery-check-if-it-is-clicked-or-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var isClicked = false;
$playPauseButton.click(function(){
if(isClicked == false){
isClicked = true;
} else {
isClicked = false;
}
```

Make a variable called isClicked and set its value to false. Then make a function that runs when the play pause button is clicked that changes the value from false to true if it’s value is false. Else it will change its value to false.

Comment: how can I check to see if a play button was clicked vs a pause button?

Comment: Make it add a class of pauseButton if you clicked the play button otherwise make it target the pauseButton class and remove the class. I usually use jquery for this so I don’t exactly know how to do this in regular JavaScript but I think you get the idea.