# Need to check if the button was clicked in order to not proceed a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

So i am trying to make a game where when "start" button is clicked the timer sets off and extra buttons appears also changing the "start" button into "pause". One of the buttons is "restart" which restarts the timer and the brings back "start" button. If "restart" was clicked while the timer was running everything goes okay. If "restart" was clicked when the timer was "paused", it resets the time, but when the game is "started" again, the basically two timers starts simultaneously. I know I would need to check whether the "restart" button was clicked and then not to start the "start" function, but I do not know how to check. I tried with "data" attribute and then put "start" function into if statement, but the function does not work then.

my code is here
https://jsfiddle.net/peliudzemas/kn3qeuct/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(playButton).on('click', function() {
    displayChange();
    $(time).text(selectedTime + " s");
  });
  startGame();
  restartGame();
});

//Action on "start game" button
//Sets off the timer, adds extra buttons
function startGame() {
  $('.startGame').on('click', function () {
    timerFunction();
    interval1();
    $(this).text("pause the game").css({
      "background-color": "#E05263",
      "color": "white"
    });

    $(this).off('click');
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('pauseGame');
    createButtons();
    pauseGame();
    });
}
//Action on "pause game" button
//Pauses the timer, changes one button
function pauseGame () {
  $('.pauseGame').on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
    $(this).off('click');
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('resumeGame');
    $(this).text("resume the game").css({
      "background-color": "#73BA9B",
      "color": "white"
    });
    resumeGame();
  });
}

//Action on "resume game" buttons
//Resumes game after it was paused
function resumeGame() {
  $('.resumeGame').on('click', function() {
    interval1();
    $(this).off('click');
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('pauseGame');
    $(this).text("pause the game").css({
      "background-color": "#E05263",
      "color": "white"
    });
    pauseGame();
  });
}

//Action on "restart game" buttons
//Resets and Stops the timer
function restartGame() {
  $(restartButton).on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().removeClass().addClass('startGame');
    $('.startGame').text('start new game').css({
      "background-color": "#73BA9B",
      "color": "white"
    });
    timer = selectedTime;
    $(time).text(selectedTime + " s").css("color", "white");
    clearInterval(interval);
    timerFunction();
    startGame();
  });
}
```

Comment: A part of me wants to suggest having multiple buttons, rather than changing the text on the same button(s).  This would drastically improve the clarity of your logic removing the need to repeatedly undo bindings, add new bindings, change text, and flip classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081608/jquery-check-if-it-is-clicked-or-not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
// just an interval set to a variable
function interval1 () {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(timerFunction, 1000);
}
...
```

[JSFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/FBlade/kn3qeuct/3/)